# Creating a unique_ptr from a pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The following code gives an error:

```
void EntityContainer::AddChild(Entity* child) 
{ 
    unique_ptr<Entity> childPtr(child);
    children.push_back(childPtr);
}
```

I take it this may not be the correct way of creating a unique_ptr to an existing object. How could this be done properly? The above code gives the following error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(617): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
```

Comment: Use `emplace_back(child)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot copy unique pointers. Because they are... unique. However, you can *move* them:

```
children.push_back(std::move(childPtr));
```

That's a bit redundant, so you could instead say:

```
children.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Entity>(child));
```

However, direct construction of container elements is already provided by the `emplace` construction:

```
children.emplace_back(child);
```

---

None of this quite hits the mark, though. The problem is really that you have a function that silently *takes ownership* of something, and that is completely invisible in the interface. So really you should change the function signature and make the caller *give* you ownership explicitly:

```
void EntityContainer::AddChild(std::unique_ptr<Entity> child) 
{ 
    children.push_back(std::move(child));
}
```

Now it is no longer your fault if the user gets the ownership semantics wrong!

Comment: Oh I see, so using push_back would create a copy somehow? If that's not the case, I don't see where the violation of copy construction is taking place.

Comment: @Tedium: Please consult [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to resolve questions like that.

Comment: So, yes XD Thanks bud.

Comment: Haha, well put. I'll be sure to check the documentation next time :)